# Leading Zeros in Java output

Tags: java, arrays

I have a file (`Multiply.txt`) that contains comma-separated pairs of integers, one pair per line.  I want to multiply the second element of each pair by the least power of 2 necessary to yield a result greater than or equal to the first element of the pair, and print each result.  For example, given a line containing "13,8", I want to multiply 8 by 2<sup>1</sup> to yield 16, and print that.

Given this input file

> 13,8
>   17,16

My program prints this output:

> 0
>   16
>   0
>   32

Instead, I expect

> 16
>   32

How can I avoid printing the two zeroes?  Here's my program:

```
/* Sample code to read in test cases:*/
import java.io.*;
public class Multiples_of_a_Number {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("multiple.txt");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            String[] power = line.split(",");
            int[] myPower = new int[power.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < power.length; i++) {
             String numberAsString = power[i];  
             myPower[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
             System.out.println(Multiply(myPower));  
            }

        }  
    }

    public static int Multiply(int[] n){
        int t= 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            if(n[1] <= n[0]){
              t = n[1] * 2;

            }else {

            }
        }
        /*while (n.length < n.length-1) {
        t = (int) Math.pow(n.length, 2);
        }*/
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiplying 8 by 2 yields 16, not 64.  Did you mean you wanted to *square* 8 (i.e. raise it to the 2nd power) to get 64?

Comment: No. You aren't making any sense !!!

Comment: i just do not want the output to display zeros at the beginning

Comment: @Dragonstone, between azurefrog and I, we have resolved the inconsistency in your example in favor of the behavior apparently intended by the program.  Please review.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to do is not display zeroes, then just only display when it's not zero:

```
System.out.println(Multiply(myPower));
```

with

```
int result = Multiply(myPower);
if (result > 0) //or != if you work with negatives
{
System.out.println(result);
}
```

Though I'd personally **highly** recommend reviewing your code.

Comment: Yes i will review my code. It seems the algorithm is not right.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three flaws in your program:

1. The inner loop in method `main()` is inappropriate.  You don't (seem to) want to process each number individually; rather, you want to process the second element of the pair in light of the first, one time.  You are getting four lines of output instead of two because of this problem.
2. Method `Multiply()` does not account for the possibility that the second number is already greater than the first (*i.e.* the case in which you must multiply by 2<sup>0</sup> == 1).  In this case it returns `0`.  One possible fix would be to initializing local variable `t` to `n[1]` instead of to `0`.
3. The implementation of `Multiply()` seems more broadly to be just wrong, however.  It is unclear why you are looping over the elements of `n` (or at least why you are starting the loop at element `0`), and it will not produce a result greater than `n[0]` if `n[1]` is less than `n[0] / 2`.  I suspect what you want to do is initialize `t` to `n[1]` and then double it as many times as necessary to increase the result above `n[0]`.  That's not at all what you actually are doing.